# Android Sqlite onUpgrade doesnt copy new column

Tags: android, sqlite

My application uses a sqlite DB, which is pre-created and copied on runtime from the assets folder. It usually works just fine. 
I have recenetly added a new column to the DB, and incremented the DB version in order for the onUpgrade method to run. this all works well, but the new DB is copied **without** the newly added column. This is the onUpgrade code:

```
//Open your local db as the input stream
                        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

                        // Path to the just created empty db
                        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                        //Open the empty db as the output stream
                        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int length;
                        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                        //Close the streams
                        myOutput.flush();
                        myOutput.close();
                        myInput.close();
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

10X!

Comment: I recommend you consider switching to [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which has all of this worked out and debugged.

Comment: at first glance it seems interesting, I will give it a try and report back :) 10X!

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Comment: Tried SQLiteAssetHelper, the problem is that it requires a sql script for the upgrade, including the old version and the new one. In my case, all I want to do, is replace the DB. I really dont want to create a script for each upgrade possible, as I have a lot of versions out there in the Android Market.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the obvious needs to be asked.  :)

Are you sure you copied the new db to your assets folder so it could be moved into the database directory again?